# Python 3 || numpy.select || Unable to get las value against condition

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to use np.select multiple conditions to create a new column, however, I am unable to get the last choice in the value. here is my code.

```
    df3 = pd.read_csv('FinalSC.csv')
    df3['Match'] = (df3['ZenotiZoneName'] == df3['AllSalon_OwnerName']).astype(str)
    df3['keyvalue'] = df3['_merge'] + df3['Match']

## Trying to put multiple condition on '_merge' column and compare two columns 'SampleZoneName' & 'AllSalon_OwnerName' 
conditions = [
    (df3['_merge'] == 'both'),
    (df3['_merge'] == 'left_only'),
    (df3['_merge'] == 'right_only'),
    (df3['_merge'] == 'both') & (df3['ZenotiZoneName'] == df3['AllSalon_OwnerName'])
]

## Here created a new column by mathching them and then applying the condition using if Match is = 'False'
conditions = [
    (df3['_merge'] == 'both'),
    (df3['_merge'] == 'left_only'),
    (df3['_merge'] == 'right_only'),
    (df3['_merge'] == 'both') & (df3['Match'] == 'False')
]

    ## Here created a One more new column by adding '_merge' + 'Match' then  using if 'keyvalue' = bothFlase
    conditions = [
        (df3['_merge'] == 'both'),
        (df3['_merge'] == 'left_only'),
        (df3['_merge'] == 'right_only'),
        (df3['keyvalue'] == 'bothFalse')
    ]

choices = ['No_Changes', 'Closed', 'New Open', 'Change in Zone']

df3['Status'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default ="")
print(df3)
df3.to_csv('temp66.csv')
```

In the above code choice 'Change in Zone' is not being picked up at any cost. I have been trying to solve this for the past 1 day and now I have exhausted all solutions online and offline. Kindly help me.

Note: Please click [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10wkH8LIHwb7kZk2TF-c-V4ZZb9HXTCa_?usp=sharing) find both the csv files.

Comment: Python is at version 3.10. Although there are multiple versions still in use, version 3.0 isn't one of them. That's the first version of "new python" and was not mature. Did you mean just "Python 3" (some reasonably current version) or are you really running python 3.0?

Comment: You could for instance check `sys.version` to see.

Comment: @tdelaney - you are correct. I meant version 3+current version & it shows 3.10.4 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df3 = pd.read_csv('FinalSC.csv')

## Trying to put multiple condition on '_merge' column and compare two columns 'SampleZoneName' & 'AllSalon_OwnerName' 

conditions = [
    (df3['_merge'] == 'both') & ~(df3['SampleZoneName'] == df3['AllSalon_OwnerName']),    ###  Here   ###
    (df3['_merge'] == 'left_only'),
    (df3['_merge'] == 'right_only'),
    (df3['_merge'] == 'both') & (df3['SampleZoneName'] == df3['AllSalon_OwnerName'])
]

choices = ['No_Changes', 'Closed', 'New Open', 'Change in Zone']

df3['Status'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default ="")
print(df3)
df3.to_csv('temp66.csv')
```

Here..

```
df3.Status.value_counts()

Change in Zone    1488
Closed              58
New Open            12
No_Changes           3
Name: Status, dtype: int64
```